# cordova-android@4.0.0 and gradle configuration in Android Studio not working

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, gradle

I have updated my Cordova project so it now uses cordova-android@4.0.0. So far it seems good but I cannot work out some things which I need to know in order to create an APK.

The newest version utilises gradle and creates an Android Studio compatible project - great! Also, you can use the new Crosswalk WebView which I decided I need to because I have seen increasing issues on older devices (typically pre-Android KitKat - 4.3 and lower). So Crosswalk seems to have overcome the issues I had and comes with a marginally noticeable increase in speed.

Anyway, a couple of issues/confusion I have been having with regards to cordova-android@4.0.0/gradle/Android Studio:

1. My armv7 APK created has now inflated from a moderate 8MB to 28MB! The www folder is the same - is there any chance it's duplicating these in the APKs generated? If not, why is it so big?
2. versionCode - the app version is set in config.xml - mine is set to 4.9.1.2. When cordova generates the versionCode (used in the AndroidManifest.xml) - Cordova has a weird parsing rule which replaces the periods '.' with '0's - but only for the first three values. So 4.9.1.2 becomes 40902. In existing versions of Cordova, you could manually edit AndroidManifest.xml and supply your own value - and Eclipse build would not overwrite this.

I have a feeling either Gradle or Android Studio is overwriting this - I cannot workout which. Please can somebody explain as I need to fix this come go-live otherwise the versionCode will not supersede my current live version of my app!

3. Gradle options - how do I set these!? There seem to be two places. I can either:

Run the following command (I will explain the extra flags in point (4))

`cordova build android --gradle --release --versionCode=49120 --gradleArg=PcdvBuildMultipleApks=false`

Or

Create a file named gradle.properties and place the following two properties in there:

```
cdvBuildMultipleApks=false
cdvVersionCode=49120
```

Both methods explained: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_platforms_android_tools.md.html#Android%20Shell%20Tool%20Guide_building_with_gradle

4. This point kinda ties in (2) and (3) - but if I can set those two options, I think I can overcome my two issues explained above! Although as a side not, the documentation states by default `cdvBuildMultipleApks` is set to false, but it isn't - in CordovaLib, the gradle build file sets it to true if it is null - am I missing something obvious here?
5. Final point and question! If I run `cordova build android` this builds my project with gradle - good! If I then open Android Studio and my project, whenever I export a signed APK, it also runs through some gradle scrips - are the two builds the same process? Do I need to run `cordova build` or does Android Studio essentially run it for me?

A long thread but I think just a few teething issues with cordova-android@4.0.0 and gradle so if you could clarify, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: OK just as a side-note, I can see Crosswalk runtime inflates the APK to > 20MB (https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/about/faq.html). That answers (1) then. But I could do with some light being shed on the remaining points please :).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. The Crosswalk contains compiled version of browser, that's why APK size increases by 12MB.
2. The versionCode calculated by Android Studio, but could be overriden by the Gradle property `cdvVersionCode`
3. When running build from the command line you could override `cdvVersionCode` by using following command

   ```
   cordova build android -- --gradleArg=-PcdvVersionCode=49120
   ```

Most likely you miss `-` before `Pcdv...` when specify --gradleArg

Second method with additional file is also viable. choose whatever will work for you.

4. To set multiple Gradle options, use

   ```
    cordova build android -- --gradleArg=-PcdvVersionCode=49120 --gradleArg=-PcdvBuildMultipleApks=true
   ```
5. The `cordova build android` and Android Studio both use Gradle to build Cordova project. They both interchangeable.

Answer (score 2):

You can also set the versionCode explicitly by:

```
<widget android:versionCode="123">
```

in your `config.xml`.

To help alleviate the APK size increased caused by Crosswalk, you can opt to use Crosswalk only for pre-L Android versions (or for pre-kitkat if you find that webview good enough). Since L has an updatable webview, it almost certainly use a version of Chromium that is the same or newer than the one Crosswalk bundles. Details in [plugin README](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview), but pasted here for convenience as well:

To build Crosswalk-enabled apks, add crosswalk plugin and run:

```
$ cordova build --release
```

To build System-webview apk, remove crosswalk plugin and run:

```
$ cordova build --release -- --android-minSdkVersion=21
```

Comment: That's most helpful - thank you! I think we'll use this as the latter WebViews work fine (KitKat onwards) so this will be so useful for that! Thanks :)

Comment: Minor correction, but it needs to be `android-versionCode` (i.e. a `-` not a `:`).

Comment: At the moment in cordova 5.1.1 this will throw an extra zero (i.e. "1230"). See here for more: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8976